# Navigating from one fragment to another using Fragment manager in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, android-fragment-manager

I am trying to navigate from one fragment to another using Fragment Manager but the app exits when the button is clicked. I tried a few solutions from the internet but
I am still not able to figure out why. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Groups.kt => The first fragment

```
package com.example.groupmail

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class Groups : Fragment(){
    private lateinit var addGroup : ImageView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_group_list, container, false)
        val recyclerview = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.group_list)
        val layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
        /*Dummy data => Remove Later */
        val dummyData = arrayListOf<GroupList>()
        dummyData.add(GroupList("group1", R.drawable.ic_settings))
        dummyData.add(GroupList("group2", R.drawable.ic_settings))
        dummyData.add(GroupList("group3", R.drawable.ic_settings))
        dummyData.add(GroupList("group4", R.drawable.ic_settings))
        /*End of dummy data */
        val adapter = GroupListAdapter(dummyData)
        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter)
        addGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.addGroupsbtn)

/* Move to next fragment on button click*/
        addGroup.setOnClickListener {
            val fragment = AddingGroup()
            fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.addgroup,AddingGroup())?.commit()
        }
        return view

    }

}
```

fragment_adding_group.xml => Layout of the second fragment

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/addgroup">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="373dp"
        android:layout_height="312dp"
        android:text="Add a Group"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.703"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NameLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#636363"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.072"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.858"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/group_name"
        android:layout_width="339dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#d4d4d4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.361"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.785"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EmailLabel"
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="234dp"
        android:text="Add Member's Email"
        android:textColor="#636363"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.175"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.566"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/member_email"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#d4d4d4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.309"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.644"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="337dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Add Group"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.519"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageAdd1"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.884"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.652"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_circle"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MessageLabel"
        android:layout_width="293dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:text="Group limit is upto 7 only!!"
        android:textColor="#636363"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.454"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.588"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MemberTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Members"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.056"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.447"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/memberRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:itemCount="5"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_memberlist_card" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Error displayed :

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and post the layout XML file for the host `Activity` and also this layout file: `fragment_group_list.xml`. The error indicates that there is no `View` with the id `R.id.addgroup` that should receive the new `Fragment`.

Comment: Please use navigation component for navigation if possible, that is way more than easy to manage all fragment and navigate them